# Error when clicking on listview Android (Java)

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I get an error whenever I click on an item in a listview from the 8th, **the previous ones work perfectly**

*Details: when clicking on the list, I call the method with the number of the item clicked, with that number instantiating a RelativeLayout with the child of the listview with the item number, then, with the layout, instantiating a TextView and a CheckBox*
**Sorry for bad English*

listview code:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p1, View p2, int p3, long p4)
{
    removerDaLista(p3);
} });
```

method code:

```
public void removerDaLista(int index){
    paraTachar.add(Integer.valueOf(index));
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)listView.getChildAt(index);
    TextView txt = (TextView) rl.findViewById(R.id.text);
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) rl.findViewById(R.id.cb);
        
    desativarLista(txt,cb);
}
```

Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mycompany.myapp, PID: 611
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity.removerDaLista(MainActivity.java:88)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity$100000001.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:71)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1164)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3132)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4059)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3818)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:10023)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2626)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2307)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:416)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1808)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3124)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:378)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10243)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4438)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4306)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3853)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3906)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3872)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3999)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3880)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4056)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3853)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3906)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3872)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3880)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3853)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6247)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6221)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6182)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6350)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6152)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:890)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:780)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is most probably the view could not be found. In your case it's the view `R.id.text` or `R.id.cb` or maybe both. Make sure those `TextView` and `CheckBox` exist in the layout or make sure you used their correct `id`.

EDIT:
It may also be an `index` problem, the `view` at that `index` could not be found. In your code:

```
rl = (RelativeLayout)listView.getChildAt(index);
```

Replace it with:

```
 rl = (RelativeLayout)listView.getChildAt(index-1);
```

Maybe the index is starting from `1` instead of `0`.

Comment: They exist and work until the eighth, but I must have been wrong about something, how would you do that code?

Comment: it didn't work, I keep having it breaking

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the error, so I read the list.getChildAt () is based on the list view and not on the adapter data.
I just had to do this

```
...listView.getChildAt(index - listView.getFirstVisiblePosition())
```